# Change peripheral timer in embedded software easy

Tags: c, design-patterns, embedded

I'm working on a an embedded software project for a microchip pic16f. This pic has only three timers.

Now i have a driver (let's call it driver A) that uses timer0 and timer1. Now i want to add functionality (driver b) to my program, but that requieres the use of timer1. But timer1 is already in use for driver A.

I can rewrite driver A so that it makes use of timer0 and timer2, so that driver b can use timer1.

But maybe in an upcoming project , i want to use my driver A, but with timer 1 and 2  so timer0 can be used for another driver c and having to rewrite my driver again.
With three timers, there aren't many possible combinations, but even with this basic cpu I'll have many different versions  of a working driver A making it impractical to manage them and fixing bugs in my code. (Imagine this driver for an mcu with more timers and even more possible ways to write Driver A)

How do you solve this problem? How can you write a driver without a hardcoded timer in it, and assign a suitable timer on initialisation? I think in c++ every timer would be an object that inherits from a timer superclass that you can pass as on object to the constructor of driverA, but i'm working in c, and therefore i can't  use objects.

Comment: What do you mean you can’t use objects? Ever heard of a struct?

Comment: Your question is way too broad and appears in the last paragraph to actually be about how OOP can be implemented in C.  That is a general question that you are far more likely to find an existing answer to, without confusing the issue by trying to make it specific to timers on a particular chip.  Also a solution is possible using compile-time binding to run-time binding to a particular timer; your C++ example suggest the latter, but that may not be either necessary or appropriate.  It could be as simple as `#define DRIVER_TIMER_A TIM1 ;` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question as asked may not have an answer that is convenient for your level of experience. The Microchip PIC16F family of controllers are so resource limited that object oriented programming techniques have limited value.

This is not to say that modular programming, limited scope, and the clean coding practices you already know aren't a huge value, they are.

If what you want is the equivalent of a generic timer class for a PIC16F you will have to write it for your application using standard C compiler constructs. The available code and RAM space of a PIC16F target will make this a challenge.

The controllers I am familiar with in the PIC16F family with only three time, usually called TIMER0, TIMER1 and TIMER2 are all very different hardware implementations. Each one of these timers has been optimized to support on-chip functions like capture of input edge events or PWM generation, or SPI timing among other things.

With these kinds of controllers the developers needs to craft the application to the available resources of the target controller. If your skill set is not well matched to these resource restricted controllers you should consider an ARM, MIPS or RISC-V class of controller.